Why does the discount price show for a second and then show the full price a second later?
So I have a gravity form that stores prices and the product variables. I have the code so that when a quantity of 3 or more it starts discounting the price per length and the total price however the discounted price per length and the total discounted price only show for a second  before it reverts back to the non discounted price.
The URL you can see this on is https://wordpress-714066-4065525.cloudwaysapps.com/product/custom-bunting/
So I have tried Price calculation code needs to be duplicated in create total price  mutation function
My code is
//Get Custom Quantity Field
                const customQuanityField = document.querySelector('.gfield--type-number input');
                customQuanityField.value = 1;

                //Get the default Quantity Field
                const defaultQuanityField = document.querySelector('input[name="quantity"]');
                defaultQuanityField.parentElement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
                //defaultQuanityField.disabled = true;
                
                let isProgrammaticChange = false;

                defaultQuanityField.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                    if (isProgrammaticChange) {
                        isProgrammaticChange = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    const quantity = e.target.value;
                    isProgrammaticChange = true;
                    customQuanityField.value = quantity;
                });

                customQuanityField.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                    if (isProgrammaticChange) {
                        isProgrammaticChange = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    const quantity = e.target.value;
                    isProgrammaticChange = true;
                    defaultQuanityField.value = quantity;
                });

                //
                //
                //Custom Bunting Update price to read £xx.xx per car flag
                //
                //

                // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
                const dynamicPriceEl = document.querySelector('.product_totals ul > li:last-of-type > div');

                const perFlagTextEl = document.createElement('p');
                perFlagTextEl.textContent = ' per length';
                perFlagTextEl.classList.add('per-length-text');
                
                dynamicPriceEl.appendChild(perFlagTextEl);

                // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
                const config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true };

                // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
                const createTotalPrice = (mutationList, observer) => {
                    console.log('createTotalPrice');
                    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
                        if (mutation.type === "childList") {
                            
                            const target = mutation.target;
                            const splitPrice = target.innerHTML.split('').slice(1).join('');
                            const calculatedPrice = parseFloat(splitPrice);

                            const totalPrice = (customQuanityField.value * calculatedPrice).toFixed(2); 
                            console.log('totalPrice', totalPrice);
                            
                            const totalPriceCalculation = document.querySelector('.total-calculated-price');

                            if(totalPriceCalculation) {

                                totalPriceCalculation.textContent = totalPrice;
                                
                            } else {

                                const totalPriceCalculationEl = document.createElement('p');
                                totalPriceCalculationEl.classList.add('total-calculated-price');
                                totalPriceCalculationEl.textContent = totalPrice;
                                target.parentElement.after(totalPriceCalculationEl)

                            }

                            //console.log(`The new list has ${mutation.addedNodes[0].children[0].childElementCount} chilren.`);
                        }
                    }
                };

                // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
                const createTotalPriceObserver = new MutationObserver(createTotalPrice);

                // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
                createTotalPriceObserver.observe(dynamicPriceEl, config);

                window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                    console.log('Script initialized');
                    
                    // DOM Elements
                    const customQuanityField = document.querySelector('.gfield--type-number input');
                    const formattedTotalPrice = document.querySelector('.formattedTotalPrice');
                    const dynamicPriceEl = document.querySelector('.product_totals ul > li:last-of-type > div');
                    const gformPrice = document.querySelector('.ginput_product_price');
                    const gformTotal = document.querySelector('.ginput_total');

                    function updatePriceDisplay(quantity) {
                        if (!originalUnitPrice || isUpdating) return;
                        
                        isUpdating = true;
                        
                        try {
                            const discount = getDiscount(quantity);
                            const discountedUnitPrice = originalUnitPrice * (1 - discount / 100);
                            const total = discountedUnitPrice * quantity;

                            console.log('Calculating prices:', {
                                originalPrice: originalUnitPrice,
                                quantity,
                                discount,
                                discountedUnit: discountedUnitPrice,
                                total
                            });

                            // Update Gravity Forms price field and trigger recalculation
                            if (gformPrice) {
                                gformPrice.value = discountedUnitPrice.toFixed(2);
                                
                                // Trigger multiple events to ensure Gravity Forms updates
                                gformPrice.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
                                gformPrice.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup', { bubbles: true }));
                                
                                // Force Gravity Forms to recalculate
                                if (window.gformCalculateTotalPrice) {
                                    window.gformCalculateTotalPrice(1); // Assuming form ID is 1
                                }
                                
                                // Update quantity field if it exists
                                const quantityInput = document.querySelector('input[name="quantity"]');
                                if (quantityInput) {
                                    quantityInput.value = quantity;
                                    quantityInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
                                }
                            }

                            // Update message
                            let messageEl = document.querySelector('.add-more-message');
                            if (!messageEl) {
                                messageEl = document.createElement('p');
                                messageEl.classList.add('add-more-message');
                                customQuanityField.after(messageEl);
                            }

                            messageEl.textContent = quantity < 3 
                                ? `Add ${3 - quantity} more to your basket to qualify for a 2.5% discount to this item.`
                                : `You're currently getting ${discount}% off this item.`;

                            // Force update total display
                            if (gformTotal) {
                                const newTotal = total.toFixed(2);
                                if (gformTotal.textContent !== `£${newTotal}`) {
                                    gformTotal.textContent = `£${newTotal}`;
                                }
                            }

                        } finally {
                            isUpdating = false;
                        }
                    }

                });
            }

        </script>


Please don't put the answer in the question, instead use an actual answer to answer your own question.

@KIKOSoftware OK I will edit my question thank you



// Remove the discount from the price to get the true base price
                        const price = parseFloat(priceText.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
                        const quantity = parseInt(customQuanityField.value) || 1;
                        
                        // Find current discount if any
                        let currentDiscount = 0;
                        for (const range in productDiscounts) {
                            const [min, max] = range.split(' - ').map(Number);
                            if (quantity >= min && quantity <= max) {
                                currentDiscount = productDiscounts[range];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        
                        // Return the original base price by removing the discount
                        return price / (1 - currentDiscount / 100);



